# Why aren't the bourbon mixins working in my jekyll site?

Tags: css, sass, jekyll, github-pages, bourbon

Every time I use `$ jekyll serve --watch` and attempt to add a bourbon mixin to my sass file, I get an error stating that the mixin is undefined.

I've checked to see if I have properly installed bourbon, and I think I have. I have verified my `@include`s to make sure they are all in order. So it *should* be working. But it isn't. I assume it's an easy fix that I just can't see.

My site is hosted by GitHub and is a modified version of the Jekyll starter template. Here's a [link to the github repository](https://github.com/ndsmith/ndsmith.github.io) for my site.

I have been trying add the mixin in the `_sass/_layout.sass` file. Specifically trying to modify the link tags in the nav bar to add a hover effect.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: What is the mixin you try to add to `_sass/_layout.sass` ? You github content does generate well, without error. I guess that @mario-araque answer can do the trick. If not, thank you to provide the code that throws the error.

Comment: Thanks for the help David. You're right, I should have included the code. But no need, @mario-araque's fix worked. (Thanks!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably you have errors because you are importing bourbon in the wrong place:

Import bourbon first in your main.sass

```
@import brbn
@import base
@import layout
@import syntax-highlighting
```